# Parse a relative link in jQuery

Tags: jquery, parsing, hyperlink

this is the output I am getting while retriving the data with Jquery

```
/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/iphone6.html
```

I want to remove everthing after the last /

result should look like:

```
/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/
```

how do I achive this task with jquery.

Comment: This is more a Javascript task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = '/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/iphone6.html';
    var ch = str.lastIndexOf('/');
    ch = str.substring(0, ch != -1 ? ch : str.length); ch = ch + '/'; 
    alert(ch);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

could be like this:

```
var url = "/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/iphone6.html"; // window.location.href;
var str = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

You can use this with native javascript methods, there is no need to use jQuery.

### [Demo](/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/)

Comment: I wanted /content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/   but I was getting /content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones with your code. the last / was also trimmed out. :|

Comment: @Pratik This won't be possible as per current code. `url.lastIndexOf('/')+1` you can see the `+1` is for that last `"\"` use it and see will update you with a demo.

Comment: I take my previous comment back. THIS code works as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf` to achieve what you need:

```
var teststr = "/content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/iphone6.html";
var result = teststr.substring(0, teststr.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: I wanted /content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones/   but I was getting /content/apple/en_US/products/apple/phones with your code. the last / was also trimmed out. :|